# unityscript, c#, boo together in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript, boo

Is it possible to use unityscript and boo together( in the same project) in unity 3d? We are trying to choose the platform and the engine to develop a game as a group and some coders are good in python and some others in js. So I will suggest unity as the engine if it is possible to combine these languages and work as a whole.

Comment: **I'd suggest having everyone learn and use the same language**, because having different bits of code written in different languages is a maintenance nightmare. Imagine one of your JavaScript developers wanting to change a piece of code written in Boo--he would have to ask one of the Boo programmers on your team to change it, or write terrible Boo code that he copied and pasted from a tutorial (thus causing bugs and other issues). Consistency is key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use all three of them in the same project. Even in the same object. In fact many of the example projects you can find on unity3d page use a mixture of JS and C#.

So technically nothing prevents you from using different languages within same project or even objects, however you should still consider to have one default language, because if you have several different languages, it will become harder for a C# developer to change code made in Boo (Python-like) if necessary and would always require him to ask the original script writer to make the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can combine the 3 languages, but not freely. There are two script tiers: Standard Assets and normal. The only way to bridge a language difference is to have a script in the normal tier reference a script in the Standard Assets tier.

More here: [Overview: Script compilation (Advanced)](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/index.Script_compilation_28Advanced29.html)